# Problems opening links on internet iphone 5S

Tags: iphone

When I search something on google and try to click on the returned items/links nothing happens. Please help, do I have to do something in my settings???

Answer (score 0):

The bug affects not only links in Safari and Mail but also in Messages. I depend on the latter for employment, and it's a race with others when notifications come through, so copy & paste is waaay too slow. Not happy!! >:-(
I'm using iOS 9.2.1

Answer (score -1):

It's an iOS bug... My 5S is also affected